# Are there any alternatives to the JTS WKTReader?

Tags: java, geometry, jts

I am using the [JTS Topology Suite](http://www.vividsolutions.com/products.asp?catg=spaapp&code=jts) to process some geometry in my application. As a starting point I instantiate a reader:

```
WKTReader reader = new WKTReader();
```

Then, using the reader I check for polygon records:

```
Geometry poly = reader.read(res.getString("GEOM"));
Geometry point = reader.read("Point(" + res.getString("LON")
    + " " + res.getString("LAT") + ")");
boolean inside = poly.contains(point);
```

The problem being that it takes too long to find my polygons this way. So I need another option for this process. Are there any alternatives to using `WTKReader` for this process? Thanks.

*P.S: I am using a MYSQL DB.*

Answer (score 0):

First, you could try to use standard java serialization/deserialization for your polygon.

Next, storing LON and LAT as STRINGs is not very effective, probably you should try numeric types.

We could get you more help if you provide the results of profiling - what consumes most of the time. However I suspect that operations with DB are the slowest one, so you may try fetch all entries once at a time, add cacheing.

Another option is to store in DB the bounding box points for every GEOM, and fetch in SQL query only that points, that belong to bounding box, and perform exact 'contains' check on java side.